# Restore overwritten Access DB in Windows

Tags: windows, backup, data-recovery, microsoft-access, file-recovery

I have an application written in C# WinForms that uses Access DBs with *.temx extension.

My client by mistake overwritten the *.temx file with ~100 records and created 4 new records inside the overwritten DB.

Can I somehow recover the previous version of the DB?

Comment: Backup. Recycle Bin. File History.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @harrymc the problem is, that no backup was created

Comment: If none of the above three exists, then it's a lost cause.

Comment: Unless the client has a recent disk image or backup, overwriting the DB with 100 records effectively removes any chance of recovery -- the data has not just been *marked* for deletion, but has been replaced.